Timeout Errors in Jupiter API
In my code made it with Node js
const executeSwap = async (quote, telegramId) => {
    try {
        logger.info('Starting executeSwap function');

        const wallet = await getWallet(telegramId);
        const connection = getConnection();

        if (!wallet || !connection) {
            throw new Error('Wallet or connection not initialized');
        }

        // Fetch the latest blockhash
        logger.info('Fetching latest blockhash');
        const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');

        // Prepare swap request data
        const swapRequestData = {
            quoteResponse: quote,
            userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
            wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
            computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 3000000, // Adjust based on priority
            computeUnitsLimit: 2368431, // Adjust based on priority
            slippageBps: 50
        };

        const response = await axios.post(`${JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT}/swap`, swapRequestData);

        const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(response.data.swapTransaction, 'base64');
        const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

        // Assign the latest blockhash
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

        // Sign the transaction
        transaction.sign([wallet]);
;
        const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
        const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
            skipPreflight: false,
            preflightCommitment: 'finalized',
            maxRetries: 3,
        });

        logger.info(`Transaction sent with ID: ${txid}`);

        // Poll for confirmation
        logger.info('Polling for transaction confirmation');
        const confirmation = await pollTransactionConfirmation(connection, txid, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds timeout

        if (confirmation.value.err) {
            logger.error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
            throw new Error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
        }

        logger.info('Transaction confirmed successfully');

        return {
            success: true,
            txid,
            explorerUrl: `${SOLANA_EXPLORER}/${txid}`
        };

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Swap execution error: ${error.message}`);

        if (error.message.includes('insufficient lamports') || error.message.includes('Insufficient SOL')) {
            throw new Error('Insufficient SOL balance for transaction fees');
        } else if (error.message.includes('block height exceeded') || error.message.includes('Signature')) {
            throw new Error('Transaction signature expired. Please try again.');
        }

        throw error;
    }
};


const pollTransactionConfirmation = async (connection, txid, timeout) => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const interval = 5000; // 2 seconds
    while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout) {
        const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(txid, 'finalized');

        if (confirmation.value || confirmation) {
            return confirmation;
        }

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
    }

    throw new Error('Transaction confirmation timeout');
};

I keep getting this errors
2024-11-25 11:40:46 [ERROR]: Swap execution error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 4YkduMMzW4dYf3XqLpvGznqHfiKqGUznfSivEyRVJXByXgDNYS3crD7Gvrtryz1p1CjbVK51h8gMjUfmJaHRwucQ using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
2024-11-25 11:40:46 [ERROR]: Swap execution error: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 4YkduMMzW4dYf3XqLpvGznqHfiKqGUznfSivEyRVJXByXgDNYS3crD7Gvrtryz1p1CjbVK51h8gMjUfmJaHRwucQ using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.

I don't know how to solve it and prevent it to make the swaps properly
I tried different approaches
but keep giving me those errors, The main problem is That I gt many timeout errors a lot just 1 of 10 Transaction pass the rest fails and the other approach dont work as well, Im using Solana/web3.js, axios and Node js in a Telegram BOT
const { PublicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, VersionedTransaction, Connection } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const axios = require('axios');

const SOLANA_EXPLORER = 'https://solscan.io/tx';
const JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v4/quote'; // Replace with actual Jupiter API endpoint

const executeSwap = async (quote, telegramId) => {
    try {
        logger.info('Starting executeSwap function');

        const wallet = await getWallet(telegramId);
        const connection = getConnection();

        if (!wallet || !connection) {
            throw new Error('Wallet or connection not initialized');
        }

        // Fetch the latest blockhash
        logger.info('Fetching latest blockhash');
        const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');

        // Prepare swap request data
        const swapRequestData = {
            quoteResponse: quote,
            userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
            wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
            computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 3000000, // Adjust based on priority
            computeUnitsLimit: 2368431, // Adjust based on priority
            slippageBps: 50
        };

        logger.info('Requesting swap transaction from Jupiter API');
        const response = await axios.post(`${JUPITER_API_ENDPOINT}/swap`, swapRequestData);
        logger.info('Received swap transaction data from Jupiter');

        const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(response.data.swapTransaction, 'base64');
        const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

    
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;


        logger.info('Signing transaction');
        transaction.sign([wallet]);


        const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();


        logger.info('Sending raw transaction');
        const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
            skipPreflight: false,
            preflightCommitment: 'finalized',
            maxRetries: 3,
        });

        logger.info(`Transaction sent with ID: ${txid}`);

        // Poll for confirmation
        const confirmation = await pollTransactionConfirmation(connection, txid, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds timeout

        if (confirmation.value.err) {
            throw new Error(`Transaction failed: ${confirmation.value.err}`);
        }

        logger.info('Transaction confirmed successfully');

        return {
            success: true,
            txid,
            explorerUrl: `${SOLANA_EXPLORER}/${txid}`
        };

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Swap execution error: ${error.message}`);

        if (error.message.includes('insufficient lamports') || error.message.includes('Insufficient SOL')) {
            throw new Error('Insufficient SOL balance for transaction fees');
        } else if (error.message.includes('block height exceeded') || error.message.includes('Signature')) {
            throw new Error('Transaction signature expired. Please try again.');
        }

        throw error;
    }
};

const pollTransactionConfirmation = async (connection, txid, timeout) => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const interval = 2000; // 2 seconds
    while (Date.now() - startTime < timeout) {
        const status = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {
            searchTransactionHistory: true,
        });

        if (status && status.value) {
            return status;
        }

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
    }

    throw new Error('Transaction confirmation timeout');
};


First of all this is not Jupiter API issue. Jupiter API just prepare transaction for you and it does not process it subsequently.
I think that you have 2 main issues on that stage: your RPC endpoint is not good enough and you do not use priority fee in your transaction. If you solve both issues you will see huge progress in landing your transactions:

RPC really matters. Use your own RPC or dedicated/shared RPC providers (Triton, Helius, Quiknode, Ankr).
You should play around prioritizationFeeLamports parameter. Without priority fee your chances of landing transaction are close to zero.

Things you also should adjust but consider it in your next steps.

Don't use strict values in swap request parameters until you understand clearly what values you should use. Jupiter has lots nice and helpful automated parameters for you to let you land your transaction with high probability: do not use computeUnitPriceMicroLamports parameterand use dynamicComputeUnitLimit=true parameter; don't use strict slippage value and start with dynamicSlippage parameter with maxBps value (or even don't use at all in swap request. Let Jupiter use recommended value from quote response).
You use sendRawTransaction method. You should consider that this is not the best method to land your transaction. Even Jupiter docs says "Due to the network congestion on Solana, the sendRawTransaction method may not be able to help you to land your transaction...".

Information may be useful for you:
Jupiter documentation - Landing transactions
Here is nice and comprehensive explanation of fundamentals. How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
